# Trying to pass in variables without using jQuery dom ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm integrating a third-party script on a Wordpress site and have run into an issue. I'm using some jQuery methods to pass some values found throughout the page and I'm then passing in those values as variables to a predefined third-party object.  The problem I'm facing is that I have to wrap the the jQuery methods with a standard jQuery dom ready function and the third-party object can't be included in the scope of the function otherwise it won't run.  So basically I'm looking for a way to pass in the variables without it being wrapped in a jQuery dom ready function. Below is the code in a bit scaled back version.

```
    jQuery(function($){ 
        var productname = $( ".product-listing").html();  
        var productprice = $( ".product-listing:nth-child(2)").html();  
        var producqty = $( ".product-listing:nth-child(3)").html(); 

        //the third-party object
        var MasterTmsUdo = {
            'CJ' : {
            'CID': '1531715',
            'TYPE': '375633',
            'DISCOUNT' : '',
            'OID': 123,
            'CURRENCY' : 'USD',
            'COUPON' : '',
            'FIRECJ' : 'TRUE',

        PRODUCTLIST : [

        { 'ITEM' : [productname],
          'AMT' : [productprice],
          'QTY' : [producqty]
        }
        }}; 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you actually "passing" anything there, but if you need your object to be in the global scope, you can assign it to a property on `window`:

```
$(function () {

    // ...

    window.MasterTmsUdo = {

    };
});
```

Of course, this will still be a problem if your third-party library tries to look for this object before DOM ready has run. We'd need to know how your third -party library works to be able to provide any assistance beyond this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I'm going to simply right the jQuery methods in standard JavaScript to avoid the problem all together.